# How many wave cycles exist in a photon?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, optics, visible-light, waves

When we say a photon is a packet of energy with frequency of f, it means it consists of at least one electromagnetic wave cycle (otherwise we can not measure its wavelength).

Is there any experiment or theory that shows how many wave cycles exist in each photon? I am asking because besides the frequency, this number also can affect the energy of the photon (a photon with two cycles should have two times higher energy than a photon with just one cycle, while they both have the same frequency and wavelengths). This is a little paradoxical to me, because as far as I know the energy of photon only depends on its frequency.

Comment: This must be a duplicate of some other question, but I can't find it.

Comment: I know exactly what you are asking. A photon has a time duration. It does not add to an electromagnetic fielld amplitude which then stays up for ever. In fact it could have started at zero amplitude and so now it only has the amplitude of one photon. But it can't stay there forever. It propagates away. It passes through a point in space in a finite time and that muliplied by the frequency gives the number you want.Furthermore I think that number must be much greater than 1 oherwise it would have a very wide Fourier transform and we could not ascribe a frequency or a wavelength to it

Answer (score 2):

A photon has no cycles.     It's like asking how many fingers does an apple have.

The thing that oscillates and has cycles is the electromagnetic field.  The photon is an excitation of the field.  Roughly speaking, adding a photon to a field means increasing the amplitude of the underlying wave.

The *size* of a photon is a different question.  It doesn't really have size either, although one can say that the size is the same as the "cavity" in which the field is defined.  To explain that in detail will take us far afield, but take as an example a laser.  The cavity of a laser is the space between the mirrors, so we can say that the photons, or excitations of the cavity modes, are the same size as the space between the mirrors.  Once outside the laser, the cavity has no boundary.  We can approximate the light field in unbounded space by a plane wave which is boundless in all directions.  For that (approximate) picture, the size of the photon is infinite.  In reality, there are no true plane waves, so the fields are always of limited extent, although it can be very large.

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer.  Actually your second part of the answer ( laser cavity and boundary part) is exactly what I am looking for. Can you suggest a good text book or reading resource please ?  It can be of huge help for me.   Thanks again.

Comment: A couple of possibilities.  "Quantum Theory of Light" by Loudon and "Laser Physics" Sargent, Scully, and Lamb.  The both have chapters on field quantization.  Slightly different emphases, so looking at both would be worthwhile.  There are probably even better ones with which I am not familiar.

Comment: Although it make more sense for photons to have the oscillating cycles. An electromagnetic field is just passing the problem on to another word. Further more its easy to physically describe an oscillating photon but no one can physically describe a field or even a wave without incorporating photons.

Comment: @BillAlsept Sensible is in the eye of the beholder.  How does one describe an oscillating photon without reference to the field?   And I think it is easy to describe a wave, we do it all the time in elementary mechanics.  And we describe an EM wave in classical EM without photons.  The OP seems to have a picture of a photon as a wave packet.  Among other things, I'm trying to expunge that compelling but incorrect picture.

Comment: There are many ways one could describe an oscillating photon. For instance it could be described the way one describes a cyclical universe expanding out and contracting in as it travels along at the speed of light. Also everyone says they can physically describe a field or wave without photons but no one ever does, ever. It can't be done.

Comment: @BillAlsept We describe fields all the time without photons.  The classical EM wave.  No photons.   We know that that's not the *best* description; the description of QED is more accurate, and that one includes photons as part of the description.  Still, it's more common to describe the field without photons than it is to describe it with photons.  (e.g. electrical engineering)

Comment: Even now you still have not described  what a field is. What's funny is even in your own words you say the most accurate description includes photons. Just like I said. No one ever describes the field or a wave without including photons. The closest they come to describing a field is calling it a wave and closest they come to describing a wave is calling it a field. That's silly.

Comment: Also I just noticed your last sentence in parentheses. I hope you were kidding about the engineering. A branch of study as in medical is an example of a field but not a light field. You can even describe a field of strawberries but you won't be able to physically describe an electromagnetic field without photons. No one ever does.

Comment: @BillAlsept  No, I wasn't kidding.  Electrical engineers frequently describe EM radiation without invoking photons.  Some EEs need to consider the quantum description if, for example, they are concerned with low intensity fields.  But an engineer designing a radio transmitter is likely not to think about photons.  His or her classical, photon-free description is adequate for the purpose.  Frankly I have no idea what you are talking about when you say "no one ever does".  That's just not true.  I'm moving on, now.

Comment: Again you did not describe a field. Could you at least give me the adequate photon free description you talk about about. Where do these engineers physically describe this field? I still have not seen anyone do it. Just give me the book and the page number please. Thanks